# How to add custom routed action as a delegate instance to ASP.NET Core 3.1 app in app.UseEndPoints?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use an local delegate instance when mapping route against its handler, namely a function that returns `IActionResult`, like a regular `Action` defined in a `Controller`.

Here is how I have tried:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.AddMvcCore();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("zh-CN"),
            new CultureInfo("ja-JP"),
        };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        RouteHandler actionA = () => new ContentResult {Content = "Hello A!"};
        ContentRouteHandler actionB = () => new ContentResult {Content = "Hello B!"};
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.Map("HelloA", context => WriteActionResult(context, actionA()));
            endpoints.Map("HelloB", context => WriteActionResult(context, actionB()));
        });
    }

    public static Task WriteActionResult<TResult>(HttpContext context, TResult result) where TResult : IActionResult
    {
        var executor = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionResultExecutor<TResult>>();
        var routeData = context.GetRouteData() ?? new RouteData();
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(context, routeData, new ActionDescriptor());

        return executor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext, result);
    }

    public delegate IActionResult RouteHandler();
    public delegate ContentResult ContentRouteHandler();
}
```

The core part is

```
RouteHandler actionA = () => new ContentResult {Content = "Hello A!"};
ContentRouteHandler actionB = () => new ContentResult {Content = "Hello B!"};
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.Map("HelloA", context => WriteActionResult(context, actionA()));
    endpoints.Map("HelloB", context => WriteActionResult(context, actionB()));
});
```

Then in the browser, the response to request `http://localhost:59716/HelloA`:

An error occured when executing `context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionResultExecutor<TResult>>();` in `WriteActionResult<TResult>()`:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionResultExecutor`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult]' has been registered.

But the response to request `http://localhost:59716/HelloB` is normal:

[image: HelloB]

I have read the source of how `IActionResultExecutor` is registered [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2e4274cb67c049055e321c18cc9e64562da52dcf/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L258) in `services.AddMvcCore()`.

But I failed to understand why it failed to handle a delegate instance of type `delegate IActionResult RouteHandler()` while it succeeded for `delegate ContentResult ContentRouteHandler()`.

My question is how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `dynamic`:

Before:

```
RouteHandler actionA =
    () => new ContentResult {Content = "Hello A!"};
```

After:

```
Func<dynamic> actionA =
    () => new ContentResult {Content = "Hello A!"};
```

Result:
[image: result of /HellA]

At runtime, `Func<dynamic>` will be resolved to the actual type `Func<ContentResult>`, so the return type of `actionA()` will be `ContentResult` and can be consumed later by `IActionResultExecutor<ContentResult>`, which has already been registered.

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection

```
    public static Task WriteActionResult<TResult>(HttpContext context, TResult result)
    where TResult : class, IActionResult
{
    var resultType = result.GetType();
    var executorType = typeof(IActionResultExecutor<>).MakeGenericType(resultType);
    var executor = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService(executorType);
    var routeData = context.GetRouteData() ?? new RouteData();
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(context, routeData, new ActionDescriptor());
    var method = executorType.GetMethod(nameof(IActionResultExecutor<IActionResult>.ExecuteAsync)) ?? throw new MissingMethodException($"Missing 'ExecuteAsync' method");
    return (Task)method.Invoke(executor, new[] {actionContext, Convert.ChangeType(result, resultType)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first route:

```
endpoints.Map("HelloA", context => WriteActionResult(context, actionA()));
```

You are calling `WriteActionResult<IActionResult>(context, actionA())`, in which causes `IActionResultExecutor<IActionResult>` to be resolved.

There is no `IActionResultExecutor<IActionResult>` by default registered. So the exception is thrown.

However, there is `IActionResultExecutor<ContentResult>` by default registerd. So when you call the second route:

```
endpoints.Map("HelloB", context => WriteActionResult<ContentResult>(context, actionB()));
```

it just works.

To fix first route, try this:

```
endpoints.MapGet(
    "HelloA",
    context => WriteActionResult(context, (ContentResult)actionA())
);
```

Or you could fix `RouteHandler` like:

```
public delegate T RouteHandler<out T>() where T : IActionResult;
```

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't solve the problem actually. It's an answer like switch-all-cases that covers all use cases.